How to add a Prometheus label to an existing Istio metric?
I have an Envoy Filter with which I'm adding the X-User-Email header containg a user email extracted from the JWT token in the authorization header.
How to add X-User-Email as a label to an existing Istio metric? For an example to the istio_request_bytes_sum{} metric.
inlineCode: |
              -- Load the JSON library
              package.path = package.path .. ";/var/lib/lua/?.lua"
              local json = require("json")
              -- Custom base64 decoding function
              local function base64_decode(input)
                  local b = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/'

                  input = input:gsub('[^'..b..'=]', '')
                  return (input:gsub('.', function(x)
                      if (x == '=') then return '' end
                      local r, f = '', (b:find(x) - 1)
                      for i = 6, 1, -1 do r = r .. (f % 2 ^ i - f % 2 ^ (i - 1) > 0 and '1' or '0') end
                      return r;
                  end):gsub('%d%d%d?%d?%d?%d?%d?%d?', function(x)
                      if (#x ~= 8) then return '' end
                      local c = 0
                      for i = 1, 8 do c = c + (x:sub(i, i) == '1' and 2 ^ (8 - i) or 0) end
                      return string.char(c)
                  end))
              end

              -- Function to parse JWT payload as JSON
              local function parse_jwt_payload(payload)
                  local claims, err = json:decode(payload)
                  if not claims then
                      return nil, "Failed to parse JWT payload as JSON: " .. err
                  end
                  return claims
              end

              -- Function to extract email from JWT token payload
              local function extract_email_from_jwt(jwt_token)
                  -- Split the JWT token into its parts (header, payload, signature)
                  local parts = {}
                  for part in jwt_token:gmatch("[^.]+") do
                      table.insert(parts, part)
                  end

                  -- Check if the token has the expected format (three parts separated by dots)
                  if #parts ~= 3 then
                      return nil, "Invalid JWT token format"
                  end

                  -- Get the payload part (second part) and decode it from base64
                  local payload_base64 = parts[2]
                  local payload = base64_decode(payload_base64)

                  -- Print the decoded payload for inspection
                  -- print("Decoded JWT payload:", payload)

                  -- Parse the payload as a JSON-like object
                  local claims, err = parse_jwt_payload(payload)
                  if not claims then
                      return nil, err
                  end

                  -- Extract the email claim from the JWT claims object
                  local email = claims.email

                  -- Check if the email claim exists
                  if email then
                      return email
                  else
                      return nil, "Email address not found in JWT token"
                  end
              end

              -- Entry point for Envoy Lua filter
              function envoy_on_request(request_handle)
                  local authorization_header = request_handle:headers():get("Authorization")
                  if authorization_header then
                      local token = authorization_header:match("Bearer%s+(.+)")
                      if token then
                          local email, err = extract_email_from_jwt(token)
                          if email then
                              -- Add email address as a header
                              request_handle:headers():add("X-User-Email", email)
                              request_handle:headers():add("x-envoy-metadata-email", email)
                          else
                              request_handle:logWarn("Failed to extract email address from JWT token: " .. err)
                          end
                      end
                  end
              end

https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/47580
I tried with applying certain telemetry definitions, but no luck.
